# Fn key not being recognized on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos

I have Logitech [K330](https://www.logitech.com/en-roeu/product/wireless-combo-mk330) unifying keyboard with **Fn** key on it. I use it on MacBook Pro 2015 with macOS Mojave. For some reason when I press Fn key it does not do anything. I definitely need this **Fn key** behavior for terminal command line navigation (Fn+Shift+Arrow keys). I tried with Logitech unifying software too, it did not work. Has anyone faced a similar situation?

Comment: Is this new behaviour since Mojave? Have you checked for new drivers/control panel?

Comment: I recently bought this keyboard. Not sure about other versions, I checked and reinstalled drivers from Logitech, nothing worked so far

Comment: Reset your Bluetooth and re-pair Logitech

Comment: Tried that, did not work

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to wait for the new driver from Logitech I think..